# Linear least squares subject to non-linear inequalities

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization

I would like to obtain a least squares solution for an **under-determined** system of linear equations,

$$Ax=b$$

where,  $A \in \mathbb{R}^{7\times9}, \, x \in \mathbb{R}^{9\times1}\text{and } b\in\mathbb{R}^{7\times1}$.

Clearly, there is no unique solution, but I would like to obtain a solution that satisfies some **non-linear inequality** conditions for a few components in $x$,

\begin{align}
f_1(x_1,x_2,x_3) &\le c_1 \\
f_2(x_7,x_8,x_9) &\le c_2 \\
\end{align}

If it helps, the starting point $x_\text{init}$ is known apriori (but I am happy to discard this knowledge if so needed).

I am happy with any solution $x^*$ that minimises $\|Ax -b\|_2$ whilst satisfying the two constraints above.

I am currently using MATLAB as my programming environment, but pseudo-code/links to useful resources etc shall be more than enough to get started. An example MATLAB code for a dummy problem shall also be very helpful.

Comment: How can you have $Ax=b$ if $Ax\in\mathbb{R}^7$ and $b\in\mathbb{R}^9$?

Comment: @TonyS.F. sorry about the typo. Fixed it to reflect $b \in \mathbb{R}^{7\times1}$

Comment: One way is to solve this as a general NLP problem, e.g. by Matlab's `fmincon`.